# Why is this placard on a Boeing 737 NG?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, boeing-737, cockpit

I was working on the cockpit of a Boeing 737 and was intrigued when I saw this placard. From what I know this has to do with Citibank being a lender or something along those lines.

Why would this be placed on the plane? Is there some kind of regulation that covers this kind of topic?

[image]

Comment: Was this on a working plane, or a display plane?

Comment: @DJClayworth This was on a working plane.

Comment: It's more likely that the lending bank requires a placard be "durably affixed" to a secured asset in their loan agreement, than any aviation regulation.  In the US, a court or creditor trying to repo a plane would have access to information about the aircraft's actual ownership by other sources.  But perhaps the idea is also that a commercial bank in, or the government of, Crobania, taking a collection action against the airline, would see the placard during a repo inspection and say "crap, the airline doesn't own this airplane, so seizing it is a losing proposition and a waste of our time."

Comment: See [this definition](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/security-interest.asp).